# Sequelize.js - bulkCreate return order

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I was wondering if the return order is guaranteed with the sequelize function bulkCreate.
I do **not** use **individualHooks**, so no parallized run.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Sequelize documentation](https://sequelize.org/docs/v7/querying/insert/#inserting-in-bulk), it looks like the returning array has the same order as the argument array:

```js
const captains = await Captain.bulkCreate([
  { name: 'Jack Sparrow' },
  { name: 'Davy Jones' }
]);

console.log(captains.length); // 2
console.log(captains[0] instanceof Captain); // true
console.log(captains[0].name); // 'Jack Sparrow'
console.log(captains[0].id); // 1 (or another auto-generated value)
```